# Python mySQL query - date between is slow unless LIMIT is added

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Having a strange issue with pymysql and python. I have a table where date_rec is one of 3 columns composing a primary key. If I do this select, it takes forever to get the result

```
    query = f"SELECT * FROM string WHERE date_rec BETWEEN {date_before} AND {date_after} ORDER BY date_rec"
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        for row in result:
            print(row)
```

However if I add a limit of 5000, it works superfast, even though there are only 1290 records to be found. The 5000 number doesn't matter... 50,000 fixes the problem exactly the same way (just as fast). As long as it's more than 1290, I get all the records.

```
query = f"SELECT * FROM string WHERE date_rec BETWEEN {date_before} AND {date_after} ORDER BY date_rec LIMIT 5000"
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        for row in result:
            print(row)
```

Can someone explain what's happening here and how to make the first case work as fast as the second? Thanks.

EDIT:

3 columns compose primary key:

1. date_rec
2. customer_number
3. order_number

So I did explain on SQL workbench and got this:

Limit-less query
[image: Limitless query]

Query with 5000 limit
[image: Limited Query]

So Mysql wasn't using the index for whatever reason. Putting in "USE INDEX(PRIMARY)" inside the query fixed the problem.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see the query plans.

Comment: It's not related to the problem, but don't substitute variables directly into the SQL, use placeholders and a parameter list.

Comment: What version  of MySQL?

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` fpr each; they may provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

I have an explanation as to why adding a `LIMIT` clause speeds up the query, but if you want to tune the query, then consider adding the following index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON string (date_rec);
```

This index will let MySQL quickly filter off records not inside the date range, and it also provides the ordering needed in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks. So this index is needed even though date_rec is already part of the primary key?

Comment: @AmeetSharma What is the primary key of your table?  What indices are on this table already?  You should include this information in your question.

Comment: 3 columns compose primary key. first is 'date_rec' I've edited the question

Comment: Then MySQL should already be able to use this index, assuming that `date_rec` is the _first_ column in the three column index.  Check the `EXPLAIN` plan to see what is going on in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Can you look at what I got with EXPLAIN on sql workbench. I've edited my question to include.

Comment: So I put in USE INDEX(PRIMARY) in my select statement... that seems to force mysql to use the index and fix the issue, whereas without that it doesn't use the index for some reason.

Comment: OK.  A single column index should suffice though, without having to force MySQL to use it.